# Error when creating new TMUX sessions while passing commands

Tags: tmux

I have a bunch of helper scripts that create (or reattach to) a named tmux session and execute a command or a script in the new tmux session.

They all work fine like:

```
cd ~/directory-of-application-starter
tmux new-session -A -s vuepress_dev "my-for-instance-app.sh whatever parameters"
```

But now... any new scripts, with the very same structure, are terminating with:

```
[exited]
```

And a `6c` which 'spills' to the next line prompt like:

```
juso@machine:~/scripts$ 6c
```

I've seen similar posts but all of them related to a misconfiguration on a .tmux.conf that I simply don't have (thus have never had to customize anything there).

Now I have a lengthy thing I have to do each time (create a python venv, activate, get a server up there etc.) and it doesn't work anymore.

Insights anyone?

Thank you.

Juso

Comment: At a glance, it seems your shell script is exiting immediately.

Comment: Yes, but only new scripts.
The old ones keep working as always

Comment: So that would lead me to believe there is something wrong with the new scripts.

Comment: That could indeed be the case but what about a linux command?

```juso@KMD01:~$ tmux new-session -A -s 'helloworld' ls```
```[exited]```

```juso@KMD01:~$ 6c ```
I am sure there is nothing wrong with ```ls```

Comment: This is precisely what I would be expecting to see when `tmux` runs `ls`. It runs the utility, it exits, and the `tmux` session exits.

Comment: That's not how it used to work with any commands or scripts in the past.
I always have to type exit to leave tmux session even after script or command completion.
And it would never print [exited] and never spill anything to the next line prompt.

Comment: You would have to inspect your older scripts to see if they postpone termination with `read` (to wait for user input) or via some other mechanic. The `tmux` utility (and GNU `screen`) has always terminated the session when the given utility has terminated.  Compare this with what happens when you run `tmux` _without_ a command: It starts an interactive shell, and then exits when the shell terminates. It's exactly equivalent to what you are observing now.

Comment: You are right in that.
I tested with "tmux new-session -A -s testname sleep 20s" and the session lasted only until command completion.